# How to find cassandra query response time?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I am trying to find out the response time of a query in cassandra using cqlsh.

I am using "tracing on" and then executing the query in cqlsh, but I get the following error:

> Statement trace did not complete within 10 seconds

This is the query that I am executing:

```
test@cqlsh:test> TRACING on;
test@cqlsh:test> select * from test limit 1;

--- output row ---
Statement trace did not complete within 10 seconds
```

Is there another way to find out the response time for the query?
Why is the trace not displayed, even when only 1 row is requested which I am certainly getting within a second?

Comment: either your cluster is hosed or `test` is very messed up. include info on cluster (`nodetool status`), your keyspace replication factor, `test`s schema and output from `nodetool tablestats`

Comment: I upgraded cassandra from 2.0.17 to 2.1.15. Can that be causing some kind of issue @ChrisLohfink?

Comment: something is likely fundamentally broken if you are getting >10sec responses. What that is, is hard to say with information provided

Answer (score 0):

For Major point release upgraded, you will need upgrade SSTables on each node.

Make sure all the node have same version

`nodetool upgradesstables`

Comment: I did that, doesn't help.